# How to work around this error? RML Utilities for SQL Server report fails to run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've used MSFT's RML utilities for several years now  and find them a great tool.

Recently I switched laptops. I installed  RML utilities, but it fails to run. It analyzes the .trc files fine, but the 'report part' fails  as follows:

> Exception Source: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
>   Message: The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
>   Stack
>   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemC
>
> Exception Source: Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
>   Message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'tmp'  Key being added: 'tmp'
>   Stack
>   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)
>   at System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary.Add(String key, String value)
>   at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken, String cmd, String currentDir,

Environment:

- Windows 7
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- RMLUtilities: "9.01.0109 built for x64"
- Reporter: 09.01.0109

Any suggestions?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: "Run as Administrator".

Opened a command  line via "Run as Administrator", then  ran the 'ReadTrace.exe' per usual

Note: our new environment has Windows UAC (User Account Control). The environment--rather than the merely a new laptop--caused the problem